Android app in C++Builder CE 11.3 fails to install - NO MATCHING ABIS
I'm creating an Android application in the Community Edition of C++ Builder Version 11.3 using Android SDK 25.2.5 32-bit.
Just testing with a simple form with a single button.  Compiles, links, packages, signs, but then chokes when installing on my Pixel Fold or Pixel 7.
Performing incremental install
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS:INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install <path to the apk>
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS:INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

I have searched for this error message with very few hits, mostly for other platforms (i.e. not Embarcadero C++Builder).  Nothing that I can apply to my situation.

I'd guess you're compiling for intel architecture, you need to compile for arm

@AlanBirtles C++Builder only supports Android on ARM, not Intel

@DarylLafferty FAIR WARNING - Android is a dead platform for C++Builder at this time. Your 11.3 CE will eventually expire and force you to install a new CE version, and Android support was removed in C++Builder 12.0. Sometime in the future they might re-add Android if they ever support Android 64bit in C++, but there's nothing in recent roadmaps for that. So, if you plan on continuing to develop for Android, you'll have to buy the full version of C++Builder/RADStudio 11.x, or else switch to Delphi.
